# How can I get last modified date of a delta table in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a delta table `dbfs:/mnt/some_table` in pyspark, which as you know is a folder with a series of .parquet files. I want to get the last modified time of that table without having to query data in the table.

If I do `dbutils.fs.ls(path)` for the table I get a modificationTime which seems to just be now() every time I query it. This makes me believe modificationTime doesn't work accurately on folders in pyspark.

I could just get the modificationTime of every .parquet file in the folder and use the greatest number, but I'd wonder if there is another already built in way, or more performant way to get the last modification time of a delta table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to do that is to [query history of the table](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#retrieve-delta-table-history) - it's relatively lightweight operation that will read that data from the transaction log:

```py
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, pathToTable)
lastOperationTimestamp = deltaTable.history(1).select("timestamp").collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: I ran this locally. It works, but it was slower than ls'ing the delta table directory and getting latest modified time. Granted it was only a few parquet files, but it took ~0.07 seconds to loop the files getting the most recent modificationTime, ignoring _delta_log. It took ~0.8 seconds using this method. I'd imagine there would be a point at which the table was so large that using this method may be more performant

Comment: When your table will grow a lot, and you'll get thousands of files, and maybe with partitions, etc., then listing operations would be slow... Also, take into account that file modification file != commit time

Comment: Depending on your storage system "scanning/listing" files can result in a significant cost..